# Converting a const to own file in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This might be a noob react question (still learning), I have this constant:

```js
const data = {
        first_name:   "John",
        last_name:    "smith",
        employee:     "Google"  
    };
```

That I pass to another function. This works but I want to move it to own file to make it more generic. If I move it to `person-data.js`:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

const PersonData = props => {
    const data = {
        first_name:   "John",
        last_name:    "smith",
        employee:     "Google" 
    };
    return (
        {data}
  );
};

export default PersonData;
```

and in my main component:

```js
import person from '../person-data'
.....
// temp to test
const data = {
        first_name:   "John",
        last_name:    "smith",
        employee:     "Google"  
    };
.....
somefunction(person) // doesnt work
somefunction(data)   // works
```

it no longer works, the reason I want to move it is so I can use props to pass the info dynamically. Is this even a good way to do this?

Comment: I have provided you with complete CodeSandBox Link also. https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-cookies-hdeiw?file=/src/PersonData.js . My answer is how we do this in React :) Check it once

Comment: I think I got your query now. When you said "but I want to move it to own file to make it more generic. If I move it to person-data.js". Generic means a seperate file with data only, not a React Component Bro :) Anyways, So, what you actually are doing is creating a seperate object to hold the data only. Is this a good Idea. I don't think so. Components are to hold state only to render that in JSX. Any way ;) That's is state management issue I guess :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because you're returning an object using destructuring syntax, without spreading the `data` object into the new object.

Try:

```js
const PersonData = props => {
    const data = {
        first_name:   "John",
        last_name:    "smith",
        employee:     "Google" 
    };
    return {...data} // or just: return data
};

export default PersonData;
```

```js
import person from '../person-data'
.....
// temp to test
const data = {
        first_name:   "John",
        last_name:    "smith",
        employee:     "Google"  
    };
.....
somefunction(person())
```

They way you have it in your code above, you are returning an object of the form:

```js
{
   data: {
      first_name: 'John',
      last_name: 'smith',
      ...
   }
}
```

Thus you would have to lookup `PersonData(props).data.first_name` to get your first name, for example.

Comment: this didnt work, I passed it like this after import `somefunction(person)`  but it is not working the same as `somefunction(data)`

Comment: Ah, that's because you're exporting a function (see edit). That is, `person` is a function, not an object. It returns an object when it is called. You're importing it and passing it as if it were still an object (like `data`)

Comment: this returned the correct data `somefunction(person())`. To better understand this, why it wasnt working with `person` if it returns the object similar to data?

Comment: Excellent. Does that answer your question, then? Or is there more I can help out with?

Comment: thanks, can you explain why I had to used `person()` and it wasnt working with just `person` ?

Comment: `const PersonData = props => {...}` stores an arrow function in the variable `PersonData`. Then `export default PersonData;` exports that variable, and again the value of that variable is the arrow function. Consequently, when you import it with `import person from '../person-data'` you're storing that arrow function in the local variable `person`. So, if you were to do: `console.log(typeof person)` you'd see: "function". For that reason, you want to *call* the function, since it *returns* the data object. So `console.log(person())` produces: "{first_name, ...}". Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `export` this file from there and `import` in your component.

**CODESANDBOX WORKING DEMO:** https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-cookies-hdeiw?file=/src/PersonData.js

**person-data.js file**:

```
const data = {
    first_name:   "John",
    last_name:    "smith",
    employee:     "Google"  
};

export default data;
```

Now in your Component import it.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import personData from "./person-data.js"; // Provide your relative path

const PersonData = (props) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(personData);
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <p>{data.first_name}</p>
        <p>{data.last_name}</p>
        <p>{data.employee}</p>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default PersonData;
```

Comment: yes, I already imported it in my other component

Comment: Then you can store it in the state. Let me update my answer further :) Wait bro

Comment: I have provided complete code in my update. If you have any questions, feel free to ask :)

Comment: Consider not returning inside a return.

Comment: @evolutionxbox: Oh dear! That was a typo  in the code. But https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-cookies-hdeiw?file=/src/PersonData.js:0-389 is my codesandbox solution :)

Answer (score 0):

```
const personData = {
  first_name: "John",
  last_name: "smith",
  employee: "Google" 
};
export default personData;
```

You can export the const. It doesn't need to be within a component. If you want to change the values, you could make a function. E.g.

```
function getPersonData(firstName) {
  return {
    first_name: firstName,
    last_name: "smith",
    employee: "Google" 
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you mean, what you have to do is to create a file personData.js with this content:

```
const personData = {
    first_name: "John",
    last_name: "Smith",
    employee: "Google"  
};

export default personData;
```

And then import the previous file where you need it

```
import personData from './personData.js';
```

and you can access to personData.first_name, personData.last_name and personData.employee where you need.

Comment: But, why would this javascript file have a .json extension?

Comment: it was a typo, fixed it